# How does this function increment?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, increment

Can someone explain how the heck below function increments:

```
function increment (i) {
  i ^= (i & ~-~i) | (~i & -~i)
  return i
}
```

I think I know javascript, but when I see something above, it pisses me off.

Comment: hint: `~i` is `-i + 1` in 2's complement.

Comment: Here's some reading to do: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: or https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: @user3477950 I think `~i` is `-i -1`

Comment: @athms I guess the OP knows Javascript, the question focuses on why that convoluted expression works as increment.

Comment: This is obsfucation for the pleasure of it : i = -(~i) will do just fine to increment without using ++ or +=1, wether i>0 or not. Funny anyway.

Comment: @Gio well, that's right

Comment: how the heck did this even get upvoted? o_O

Comment: @user3477950: why do you think this doesn't deserve upvote?

Answer (score 5):

Boolean algebra 101.

First, under the assumption that we are working with [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), this is the definition of unary minus operator `-` (see the footnote too):

```
-A = ~A + 1
```

Here is your RHS expression, with some extra parenthesis added, without the shortcut assignment and with all operators in extended form for better readability:

```
i xor ((i and ~(-(~i))) or (~i and -(~i))
```

We apply the first relation:

```
i xor ((i and ~(~~i + 1)) or (~i and (~~i + 1))
```

complement operator `~` is idempotent, meaning that `~~i` is equal to `i`, so we simplify:

```
i xor ((i and ~(i + 1)) or (~i and (i + 1)))
```

the second term of the `xor` operator has the `(X and ~Y) or (~X and Y)` form, which means *"one of X and Y must be true for the expression to be true, but not both"*, which the very definition of exclusive or (`xor`), so we can replace that with `X xor Y`, obtaining:

```
i xor (i xor (i + 1))
```

we change the association (`xor` is associative) and we get:

```
(i xor i) xor (i + 1)
```

`i xor i` is a contradiction (always `false`), so we get:

```
false xor (i + 1)
```

note that the truth value of `false xor X` depends entirely on `X`, so we can rewrite the above as:

```
i + 1
```

So the RHS evaluates to `i + 1`. We replace it in the original code and we get:

```
function increment(i) {
    i = i + 1
    return i
}
```

Voilà!

**NOTE**: `+` should be formalized as another operator if we wanted to be fully formal. In this case, we can safely skip the definition and keep it a black box, since we did not need any of its properties. The only thing that matters is that `~` has a higher priority than `+`.

Comment: Maybe use `0` instead of `false`?

Comment: @Bergi all the expressions should be intended as (more or less) boolean algebra expressions, not as JS code (although they are valid JS too) :)

Comment: But they do operate on "arrays of booleans" actually - so `[false * 32]` :-)

Comment: Wow, all this could even be replaced with `return i++` correct?

Comment: @MBottens: No (postfix pitfall #1). `return ++i;` if at all. But `return i+1;` is simpler

Comment: @Bergi this is the beauty of a purely syntactical manipulation. They could be integer, boolean or even potatoes. I simply applied the algebraic operator properties, without giving any meaning to the symbols being manipulated, other than the _"same symbol means same value"_ assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shorter proof, automatically generated by [my website](http://haroldbot.cloudapp.net/test.html?q=i%20%5E%20%28%28i%20%26%20~-~i%29%20%7C%20%28~i%20%26%20-~i%29%29)

```
i ^ (i & ~-~i | ~i & -~i)
definition of xor
i ^ i ^ -~i
xor with self
-~i
definition of two's complement
~~i + 1
double complement
i + 1
```

In the step "definition of xor", the definition `x ^ y = x & ~y | ~x & y` is used, with `x` being `i` and `y` being `-~i`.

In the step "definition of two's complement", the definition `-x = ~x + 1` is used, with `x` being `~i`.

Comment: Nice, unfortunately it's hard to see what exactly "definition of xor" does replace on the website. Maybe you could use some more colors?

Comment: @Bergi that's a good idea, I'll see what I can do (will take a while though)